# Discord.js v13 mention a role but it doesn't ping

Tags: javascript, discord.js, mention

I have been trying to get my bot to ping a certain role by doing.

```
client.channels.cache.get('927271117155074158').send(`<@&924403524027154513> nota is ${statestart}`)
```

And it will show the role like this [how it shows in discord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fadA4.png).

But it doesn't actualy ping the role.

How do i ping the role?

I am using Discord.js V13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.
I didn't know i had to allow role mentioning in the client

```
        super({ intents, allowedMentions: { parse: ['roles'], repliedUser: false } });
```